# Curious behaviour on SSH-Console?

Tags: linux, ssh, console, debian

I'm very new to Linux and hava a curious behaviour here, which I don't know if it is ok, or if there is something wrong.

I logged in to SSH via Putty and changed some directorys. When I press the UP-Arrow, the console lists the last commands which were executed. 
Between those I found a

"**iptables -S**" (??) and a

"**vi etc/iptables/rules.v4**" and also a

"**vi ~/.ssh/known_hosts**"

I know that my admin has made some changes to iptables, but that was ca. two weeks ago(!) .. is it correct, that when I login with Putty today, the list of commands shows me those mentioned above?? Or is there someone on my server??

Comment: Did you logged as the SAME user you usually work with ? If your admin logged as root two weeks ago and you just logged as root again, you will see the last commands run for this session, and not for your "default" session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing these commands because these commands are executed, so it will be stored in Bash log for few days. You can use history command to list all the executed commands.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have logged in with the same user my admin has used, but are those commands stored for so long? .. I mean, it was like 2 weeks ago (?)

Comment: The log file size depend on two values HISTFILESIZE and HISTSIZE

Comment: Also, the log file will typically be from the latest session which logged *out* because there is a single history file but you can have many shells running concurrently.

Comment: ok, thank you very much :)